# annotating st_sample random points with an identifier that matches original dataframe

Tags: r, gis, r-sf

I'd like to create 20 random locations within a 15 km radius around every GPS location of an animal track (see example).

[image: animal track with behavioral classifications]

I can do this with `st_buffer` and `st_sample`, but I'm having trouble annotating the randomly sampled locations with the track ID (total IDs ~ 200). I need to annotate the randomly sampled locations so that I can join this dataframe back with to the observed track locations where each of the 20 random locations are associated with an observed location and id.

A simple example of the dataframe looks like this where I have an animal identifier (id), geographic coordinates (x,y), and a timestamp (time):

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("id1", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2"),
           long = c(-80, -81, -82, -79, -70, -75),
           lat = c(36, 37, 38, 41, 40, 40.5),
           time = c(7, 8, 9, 6, 7, 8)
  
)
```

I was wondering if maybe I could name the buffers by `id` column and then `st_join` the random locations to the buffers so that the randomly sampled locations would have the column identifier in the original dataframe? But would that satisfy annotating the locations with the observed location? Just a thought. My code so far looks like this.

```
random_locs <- df %>% 
  st_as_sf(., coords = c("x","y"), crs = "epsg:4326") %>% 
  st_transform(., crs = "epsg:26915") %>%
  #filter(class == "stopover") %>% # don't worry about this
  group_by(id) %>%
  st_buffer(., dist = 15000) %>% 
  #st_dissolve(.) %>%
  mutate(BirdsID_season = BirdsID_season) %>% # can I add a name to the buffers?
  st_sample(., size = rep(20,nrow(.)), "random", exact = TRUE) %>% 
  st_as_sf(.) %>% 
  mutate(used = 0) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

The output is correct in terms of the number of locations but I don't have any information to annotate the original identifier to join the dataframes. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**
I'm editing the question to detail my desired output: The end goal is to have observed locations (= 1) and random locations (= 0) in a tidy framework. Random locations must be generated conditionally upon observed locations (time, x, y) and animal_id and be annotated as such in order to generate a single binomial response (0/1, TRUE/FALSE, observed/random). The output would look something similar to the df for two individuals below. I simply added 3 rows to the original df where for each used location, 1 random location was generated per id:

```
final_df <- data.frame(id = c("id1", "id1", "id1", "id1", "id1", "id1",
                              "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2"),
                       long = c(-80, -81, -82, -82,-82.5, -81
                                -79, -70, -75, -82.5, -79.5, -79),
                       lat = c(36, 37, 38, 37, 36.5, 37,
                               41, 40, 40.5, 40, 42, 40.5), # these are all made up
                       time = c(7, 8, 9, 7, 8, 9,
                                6, 7, 8, 6, 7, 8), # time wouldn't change w/ addition of random locs
                       type = c("1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0",
                                "1", "1", "1", "0", "0", "0") # or TRUE/FALSE, yes/no, observed/random
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use rowwsie grouping to work with each individual location point when creating buffers and taking samples. Every observed point is replaced by a `MULTIPOINT` (the result of `st_union()`) of 20 random points, resulting geometry column is then cast to `POINT`.

When stacking both datasets with `bind_rows()`, we can use `.id` argument to get identifier column.

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.3, GDAL 3.5.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(dplyr)
library(mapview)

df <- tibble(
  id = c("id1", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2"),
  long = c(-80, -81, -82, -79, -70, -75),
  lat = c(36, 37, 38, 41, 40, 40.5),
  time = c(7, 8, 9, 6, 7, 8)
)

### stacking observed and random points
# sf from input data:
locations_sf <- df %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("long","lat"), crs = "epsg:4326") %>% 
  st_transform(crs = "epsg:26915")

# sampled points
sample_sf <- locations_sf %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(geometry = st_buffer(geometry, 15000) %>% st_sample(20) %>% st_union()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  st_cast("POINT")

# bind together, name ("observed" / "random") will be used for a type column
stacked_sf <- bind_rows(list(observed = locations_sf, random = sample_sf), .id = "type") 

stacked_sf
#> Simple feature collection with 126 features and 3 fields
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 1455288 ymin: 4050203 xmax: 2479757 ymax: 4702531
#> Projected CRS: NAD83 / UTM zone 15N
#> # A tibble: 126 × 4
#>    type     id     time          geometry
#>  * <chr>    <chr> <dbl>       <POINT [m]>
#>  1 observed id1       7 (1674746 4063075)
#>  2 observed id1       8 (1569850 4162867)
#>  3 observed id1       9 (1467197 4263375)
#>  4 observed id2       6 (1678983 4634280)
#>  5 observed id2       7 (2471421 4689820)
#>  6 observed id2       8 (2028860 4642061)
#>  7 random   id1       7 (1661987 4056629)
#>  8 random   id1       7 (1662872 4070261)
#>  9 random   id1       7 (1664411 4054672)
#> 10 random   id1       7 (1667414 4075791)
#> # ℹ 116 more rows


# back to data.frame / tibble with separate columns for lat/lon
final_df <- stacked_sf %>% 
  st_transform("WGS84") %>% 
  { bind_cols(st_drop_geometry(.), st_coordinates(.)) } %>% 
  select(id, long = X, lat = Y, time, type)
```

Result:

```
final_df
#> # A tibble: 126 × 5
#>    id     long   lat  time type    
#>    <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   
#>  1 id1   -80    36       7 observed
#>  2 id1   -81    37       8 observed
#>  3 id1   -82    38       9 observed
#>  4 id2   -79    41       6 observed
#>  5 id2   -70    40       7 observed
#>  6 id2   -75    40.5     8 observed
#>  7 id1   -80.1  36.0     7 random  
#>  8 id1   -80.1  36.1     7 random  
#>  9 id1   -80.1  35.9     7 random  
#> 10 id1   -80.1  36.1     7 random  
#> # ℹ 116 more rows

# visualize points for one id/time:
stacked_sf %>% filter(id == "id1", time == 7) %>% 
  mapview(zcol = "type", map.type = "CartoDB.Positron")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-07-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I think this a really great example and I definitely learned something here. But I think the answer is incomplete, namely b/c I didn't articulate exactly what I wanted. I need them in a tidy frame work, with the random locations stacked on the observed locations. So I think adding to your answer, we may simply be able to `locsdf <- random_locs %>% st_cast(., "POINT") %>% mutate(type = "random") %>% bind_rows(.,df)`? Something like that? Where we add an identifier of  `type` = "random"` to `random_locs` and stack atop the original dataframe? Let me know, not 100%

Comment: I think I get what you are after, but just to be sure, could you please add desired output to your question? While tibble / data.frame/ sf  object in a reproducible form would be great,  just something that would describe what columns and column types you are expecting would do just fine. And perhaps include some context, so we'd know what will happen next. I.e should it still be an `sf` object that will be used for maps and/or saved in some spatial file format?  Or perhaps a data.frame, with similar structure as your input, that can be saved as CSV?

Comment: Thank you @margusl. I provided more detail in my edit to the original question. The aim is to generate a "binomial" (or more technically "Poisson") response (0/1) in a single vector where observed locations = 1 and random locs = 0. The next step is to extract spatial variables at all locations, and the final step is to model 0s vs 1s to determine decisions/preference/etc. Random locations are generated conditionally by used location and id for statistical robustness - these categories will be used to control for spatial (lat/long) and temporal autocorrelation (multiple locations/id).

Comment: Thanks, that last edit should address this.

Comment: This is excellent. I'm most appreciative and I've never seen it done this way before. Thanks for the simplicity and the mapping for proof of concept.